# Error while conversion of Nhibernate query to generic list

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I have a simple entity called `EmployeeEntity` with properties `ID`, `Name`, `Age`, `Organisation`, and `Designation`. I am just querying the database using the query

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(
    "select Name, Designation, Age, Organisation FROM EmployeeEntity " +
    "group by Name, Designation, Age, Organisation");

IList<EmployeeEntity> employee = query.List<EmployeeEntity>(); // Throws error
```

but on conversion to my type, it's throwing an exception:

> Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available]

with `InnerException`:

> The value "System.Object[]" is not of type "NHibernateTest.EmployeeEntity" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
>   Parameter name: value

though it works fine using this query:

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("select e FROM EmployeeEntity e group by e");

IList<EmployeeEntity> employee = query.List<EmployeeEntity>();
```

but I don't want to select all the columns because I don't need them.

Answer (score 14):

If you only want a certain set of columns, create a class that maps one to one with your columns. Like so:

```
public class EmployeeView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
}
```

You then just need to add a result transformer to your query

```
IQuery query = session
    .CreateQuery("select Name ,Designation ,Age ,Organisation  FROM EmployeeEntity   group by  Name ,Designation ,Age ,Organisation")
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<EmployeeView>());

Ilist<EmployeeEntity> employee= query.List<EmployeeView>();
```

Comment: Hi Vadim,
Thanks for your reply . Do you means to say i have make a different class every time I have select a few column from the entire entire table. If so my classes will grow according to the selection.

Comment: @pijush, it is a fairly common practice, see here for a good discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636769/using-dtos-and-bos

Comment: thanks for the help.. I think i can go ahead with your suggession.

Answer (score 5):

When you're querying with `select Name, Designation, Age, Organisation...`, NHibernate will actually return an `IList<object[]>` instance. To overcome this, try rewriting your HQL to `select new EmployeeEntity(Name, Designation, Age, Organisation)...` and add an appropriate constructor to `EmployeeEntity` class.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but on adding constructor and than querying..it gives me this exception "NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException: The following types may not be used as proxies:
NHibernateTest.EmployeeEntity: type should have a visible (public or protected) no-argument constructor"
   
which means an entity with constructor is not supported by nhibernate.

Comment: @pijush, it only means that you can't have just a non parameterless constructor. Simply add a parameterless constructor and you're good to go.