# NHibernate error system.object[] when retrieving multiple entities in one query

Tags: select, nhibernate, hql

I have a HQL query like this:

```
 string  QueryString =   select client, transporter 
    from BaseClient as client, BaseTrans as transporter
    where client.tr = transporter.Id and transporter.badge = 1
    order by transporter.date;
```

But when I use this `hql` I receive the following error :

> The value `"System.Object[]"` is not of type `"xxx"` and cannot be used in this generic collection.
>   Parameter name: value

Just like [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474258/error-while-convertion-of-nhibernate-query-to-generic-list) but, when I omit the `Transporter` entity in my select it works.

Like :

```
string  QueryString =  select client
 from BaseClient as client, BaseTrans as transporter 
 where client.tr = transporter.Id and transporter.badge = 1
 order by transporter.date;
```

But I need transporter in my select, because I use order by.

By the way, I have 2 hbm Client.hbm.xml and Transporter.hbm.xml. Each hbm have their own Class and Table.

i call it with :

```
IQuery requete = this.CreateQuery(QueryString);

   IList<Client> executions = requete.List<Client>();
```

it hang on this line, when hibernate try to convert to the list

Comment: How does your code look like where you call this HQL ?

Comment: thanks you for responding, i modifie my question. i add the line how i call it

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your result-set will likely be a multi-dimensional array where the first column represents a Client and the 2nd column contains a Transporter.

What happens if you change your code like this:

```
IQuery requete = this.CreateQuery(QueryString);

var result = requete.List();

var clients = result[0] as IEnumerable<Client>;
```

(I have no NHibernate installed on this system so I cannot just test something out quickly without creating and setting up a new project. :)