# Why CreateSQLQuery throwing exception "The value System.Object[] is not of type and cannot be used in this generic collection"?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
[Id]    [INT] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT A_P_KEY PRIMARY KEY,
[X] [INT]
)
```

Following is entity class:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int X { get; set; }
}
```

Following is mapping:

```
internal class AConfiguration : ClassMapping<A>
{
    public AConfiguration()
    {
        Table("A");

        Id(x => x.Id, im =>
        {
            im.Column("Id");
            im.Generator(Generators.Identity);
        });
        Property(x => x.X, map => map.NotNullable(true));
    }
}
```

Following is how I call the `CreateSQLQuery`:

```
List<A> lst = null;
using(var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    lst = session.QueryOver<A>().List<A>().ToList();//This works

    var sql = @"SELECT Id, X FROM A";
    lst = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).List<A>().ToList();//This fail
}
```

As shown above, the `QueryOver` call works correctly. But the `CreateSQLQuery` call fails with following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The value "System.Object[]" is not of type "[....].A" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: value
  ParamName=value
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowWrongValueTypeArgumentException(Object value, Type targetType)
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object item)
       at NHibernate.Util.ArrayHelper.AddAll(IList to, IList from)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ListCustomQuery(ICustomQuery customQuery, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List[T](NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.List[T]()
       at [....]
  InnerException:
```

Why `CreateSQLQuery` call is throwing exception?

The answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5474258/5779732) question are not helpful as I am selecting all the columns from the table; that question talks about selecting limited columns.

Answer (score 5):

The `CreateSQLQuery` API will return object array `System.Object[]`. The exception is while attempting to map this object array with your entity.

You have two ways:

1. Get object array and map manually

   You can get the object array using `session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).List<Object[]>()` and map it further with your custom logic. Refer to [this](https://www.journaldev.com/3422/hibernate-native-sql-query-example) or [this](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2013/04/sessioncreatesqlquery.html) resource for more details.
2. Instruct NHibernate how to map it

   NHibernate have feature called `Transformers`. Transformers help mapping complex objects. You can use one something like below:

   ```
   lst = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql)
       .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<A>())
       .List<A>()
       .ToList();
   ```

   Refer to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm) resource for more details.